# How to apply hampel filter to first and last k values in a time series in R?

Tags: r, time-series, filtering, data-cleaning

I am using the `hampel` method from the `pracma` package to filter outliers in my time-series data. However, `hampel` does not filter outliers among the first and last k values in the data, instead replicating them as it is.

Is there an alternative moving average filter for outlier detection in R which can wrap around the series while considering the first and last k values? If not how do I utilize `hampel` to do this on my own?

For example, I have the original series `orig` and the filtered series `filt` as below:

```
> orig<-c(26L, 34L, 29L, 49L, 24L, 28L, 30L, 26L, 33L, 25L, 33L, 43L, 20L, 26L, 32L, 21L, 28L, 28L, 18L, 28L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 22L, 27L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 28L, 33L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 20L, 27L, 24L, 27L, 23L, 23L, 22L)
> filt<-hampel(orig, k=6)$y
```

Plotting them gives these:
[image: original]

Filtering produces the below series:
[image: filtered]

As you can see, the very obvious outlier at index 4 is not filtered, because the first 6 values are replicated as they are.

Assuming I cannot change the value of 'k', how do I ensure the corner values are also filtered?

Comment: You could, for example, simply repeat the first three points at the beginning, and the last three points at the end. `hampel(x,k=6)` will then return indices 7 and 15, that is the points with indices 4 and 12 of the original series. This can easily be automated.

Comment: @HansWerner in a time series, would that not disturb the trend of the data? Also, if I repeat the first k points, any outliers within these points will also be repeated.

Comment: Absolutely right; that's why I entered my remark as a comment, not a solution. Think of it: Identifying outliers is problematic and it is still more problematic at the boundaries. If you don't care you could change `hampel` such that for the first (and also last) `k` points it will take as (constant) context these `k` points -- only a few lines to add to the function.

Comment: @HansWerner unfortunately, that does not work with my data. Thanks for the suggestion though